# 'Having brains' or 'with brains'?

Tags: american-english, spoken-english

What's the correct phrase?

Example:

> She wants to marry a guy **with brains**.

Or

> She wants to marry a guy **having brains.**

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=With+brains%2C+having+brains&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2CWith%20brains%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bwith%20brains%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BWith%20brains%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BWith%20Brains%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bwith%20Brains%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Chaving%20brains%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bhaving%20brains%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BHaving%20brains%3B%2Cc0

Comment: a guy with brains, although you could just say an intelligent guy

Answer (score 1):

**With brain** used to indicate the manner or attitude of the person doing something that shows that he has a good thinking

**Having brain** means the person own a brain.

*She wants to marry a guy having brains* is ungrammatical. It should be

> She wants to marry a guy that has a brain

Regardless, this sentence doesn't make sense because everyone has a brain.

Answer (score 0):

'With brains' is more like an adjective, describing a trait for an individual, like saying 'a guy with a limp' or 'a guy with a big nose'.

'Having brains' is much less commonly used, and is usually a more general description of someone's behavior, like 'people who have enough brains to drive carefully'.

Comment: I still didn't get it. Which one is used to show intelligence?

Comment: They both can be used to mean a person with intelligence, but they are used in different circumstances or different frequencies.